# Click on Small Image and Overlay Bigger Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have several images in a grid. I want each image to overlay to fullscreen when I click on them. 
I have this javascript on there, but when I click on the image the one that overlays is the last image on the grip. How should I fix that?

I'm using this, but I have several images:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8c9P/

The only the difference on mine from this is that it is in another div for another javascript that puts it into the grid.

HTLM:

```
<div class="brick">
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="overlayContent">
<img class="imgBig" src="img/Scan.jpg" />
</div>
<img class="imgSmall" src="img/Scan.jpg" height="345">

</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a8c9P/192/ is this you wanted?

Comment: @Cattla this what I have. I have to keep it in the freewill div because it is running something else. I know it's not showing or working  http://jsfiddle.net/PaulinaPaulino/4pvc5h0j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check out this
```

are you trying for this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lqsmr4bu/

Comment: yes, that is what I want, and I tried it and it's not showing the overlay image. I barely know javascript or jQuery, but why is the imgBig empty? @sarath

Comment: is your problem solved?  are you asking about the working of the code?

Comment: I did what you showed me but it is not working. This is how my stuff kinda looks like. http://jsfiddle.net/PaulinaPaulino/4pvc5h0j/

Comment: But still its working for me. Also in your fiddle you didn't include jquery. Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/nt80hgeq/. This is your code and I included the jquery to it and nothing else. Also i've commented some portion of your code. What you are trying to do with the commented portion? Also let me know is this you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I was doing the javascript wrong. Thank you so much!!! it is working now. The section you putted on comment was the javascript for something else.